# Creating hub page with different controls in Windows 8

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

The most landing/hub pages you see are just a **GroupedGridView** ( for example the actual marketplace app )

But I would like to have a Grouped hub page with different controls.

For example my first control is a ListView that contains some categories. 
2nd and 3th control are GridViews with several items in them.

If all 3 controls were GridViews I could easily get this working but it's not.

I can't seem to find a working combination of  ScrollViewer with a Grid or Stackpanel to get the actual full Horizontal Scrolling working.

Any idea's or examples on how to create such a landing/hub page with different controls in one horizontal page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an GridView that is not grouped where each item will be a different control displayed using a different DataTemplate.

Or you can trick the FlipView to behave like a Panorama control for Windows Phone. Details at http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.cz/2012/08/a-winrt-behavior-to-turn-flipview-into.html

**EDIT**:
For the first solution you create a base class and create a list with your different objects derived from the base class. Then you use the GridView's ItemTemplaceSelector to select a select an appropriate DataTemplate. See http://coding.kulman.sk/using-different-data-templates-with-gridview-in-windows-8-apps/

Comment: So if I get this correctly that means the controls that I want to add is the ItemSource for the GridView? And I should make some base class that each control uses so I can set a List<BaseClass> for the itemsource? And then depending on the actual class for the item display a other template.

Comment: see my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795937/windows-store-app-eliminates-gridview-styles-and-use-only-for-hub-page-layout if anyone who want to remove GridView default interaction style for hub page.