# Windows Store App: Eliminates GridView styles and use only for hub page layout

Tags: microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I try to make a Windows Store App (Metro) hub page which has four different templates with GridView.

I referenced [link](http://coding.kulman.sk/using-different-data-templates-with-gridview-in-windows-8-apps/) in [Creating hub page with different controls in Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155905/creating-hub-page-with-different-controls-in-windows-8) page and it works fine.

But GridView has a default style which interacts with touch(and mouse) activity.
It grayed when hover, and shows click interaction.

My question is, how to disable those behaviors?
I tried to dig with Blend but hard to find the place to be customized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry I don't know MS Blend

But in visual studio please follow below instruction :

1. right click on your grid
2. go to Edit Additional Template
3. click on 'Edit Generated Item Container(ItemContainerStyle)' > 'Edit a Copy...'
4. go to XAML code and remove the PointerOver content from your code. the code should be like the following

   ```
     //some code here

   <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
      <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverPressed"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

       //continue
   ```